# "On" doesn't work with "Load" event

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to attach a load event on images as they appear without waiting for the document to finish loading. So i'm using `$.on` to achieve this rather than putting my code in the bottom of the page but it's still not working.

My html is like:

```
<script>
  $('img').on('load', function(){
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
  });
</script>

<img src="koala.png" />
```

This doesn't actually work, But this does: (which is not what i want)

```
<img src="koala.png" />

<script>
  $('img').bind('load', function(){
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
  });
</script>
```

Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: Try using a document.ready with that? And it will probably not work with cached images, but who knows ?

Comment: AFAIK, live() didnt work with the load event. So i dont think on() will either

Comment: @adeneo As i said i don't want to wait for the document to finish.

Comment: @Ryan - you're using jQuery 1.7+ correct?

Comment: @Ryan use `live` instead of `on`

Comment: @mgraph I already did, In fact `live` is deprecated anyways.

Comment: Not the best solution in the world, but if you're primarily trying to manipulate the image attributes before it is displayed to the user, then you can do your magic with the image in a hidden div and then remove the hidden class after your done.  Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rp5xg/).

Answer (score 0):

There are several known caveats with this that should be noted.

- It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
- It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the
  same src as before
- It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
- Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

From [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get the question at all, but try placing this **below** the images in the DOM:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
        img.src = images[i].src;
        img.onload = loaded(images[i]);
}

function loaded(image) {
    image.style.border = '20px solid red';
}
```